# Problem with PrestaShop price rounding tax exclude

Tags: prestashop, price

After upgrading to version 1.7.4.0, I have a problem with PrestaShop net prices.
Where to look for the function responsible for net prices?
How to repair?

Screen with problem

[image: snap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go directly to your database with PhpMyAdmin.

Find **ps_currency** table.

Look for ﻿**precision**﻿  column there and change the number from 6 to 2.

Comment: I was glad to help! :)
Please, mark this question as resolved.  To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is:

- Go to Admin -> Shop Parameters -> General
- **Set round mode as 2**

and it's done!

Comment: Already configured that way and stil have the issue. I think the perfect solution are from @Vince.